# Prove $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(\cos(x))dx = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(\sin(x)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-writing

Assume $f$ is *continuous*, prove $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(\cos(x))dx = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(\sin(x))dx$. Of course this immediately brings to mind of the relation between $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$. I know that $\cos(x)=-\sin(x+\pi)$. So should I rewrite the sine function like this? I've tried this and it does not seem to help. Any answers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**: $\sin(x) = \cos\left(\dfrac\pi2-x\right)$.

Comment: I used the property $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(cos(\frac{\pi}{2})-x)dx= \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(cos(\frac{\pi}{2}))dx - \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(cos(x))dx$

Comment: Is this right? I tried it

Comment: And then when I calculate it it's $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(0)dx+ \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(cosx)dx$. What to do with the f(0). Thanks